# size() function not working in Processing 3.0

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to set size of the window in [Processing 3.0](http://processing.org/) by passing the parameters from the image width and height. However, Processing is throwing an error and asking to check the Reference section which isn't helpful. Code is below.

```java
PImage img;
...

void setup(){
  img = loadImage("XYZ.JPG");
  float w = img.width;
  float h = img.height;
  size(int(w), int(h));
  image(img, 0, 0);
}
```

and error below:

```java
size() function cannot be used here
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the `size()` function from the `setup()` function, then it has to be the **first** function you call, and you can't pass variables into it.

If you really need to pass variables into the `size()` function, then use the `settings()` function instead of `setup()`.

```java
PImage img;

void settings(){
  img = loadImage("XYZ.JPG");
  float w = img.width;
  float h = img.height;
  size(int(w), int(h));
}

void setup(){
  image(img, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The message ***`size() function cannot be used here`*** applies to 3.1.1.

I had this problem until I move the `setup()` method in the "root" pde (the left most tab in the IDE).

Comment: Your answer solved my problem: In my case, the first tab didn't even have a sketch. But removing that empty tab solved the problem. I think this is a bug in processing.